# Use Rufus scheduler to call my Model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rufus-scheduler

I am trying to use rufus-scheduler to call my Ruby on Rails Model called `HelloWorld`.

However the below is failing with the following error in my console:

`scheduler caught exception:`

`undefined method 'Foo' for #<Class:0x23371e0`
 `================================================================================
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method 'Foo' for #<Class:0x23371e0>
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in 'method_missing'
C:/my-dash/config/initializers/scheduler.rb:6:in 'block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in 'call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in 'trigger_block'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in 'block in trigger'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in 'call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in 'block in trigger_job'`

I assume I am not calling my Model from the Scheduler correctly?

Inside file `'config\initializers\scheduler.rb'` I have the following:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.every '10s' do      
 HelloWorld::Foo.new
end
```

My Model class called `HelloWorld` in `'app\models\helloworld.rb'` contains:

```
class HelloWorld < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :my_name

 def Foo
  my_var = "Some text here"
  #and then do some more stuff here...
 end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you call HelloWorld::Foo.new outside of the scheduler (from a controller for example)?

Comment: Please include as well the complete backtrace of the error, not just the beginning of its first line.

Comment: @jmettraux Updated with full error now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
HelloWorld.new.foo
```

instead of

```
HelloWorld::Foo.new
```

Your issue has nothing to do with rufus-scheduler or Rails, it's just you trying to call an instance method directly on the class. Take the time to learn Ruby.

You can play with this program, just Ruby and you, no Rails, no rufus-scheduler:

```
class HelloWorld
  def Foo
    puts "Foo"
  end
end

begin
  HelloWorld::Foo
rescue => x
  p x
end

begin
  HelloWorld::Foo.new
rescue => x
  p x
end

begin
  HelloWorld.new.Foo
rescue => x
  p x
end
```

Running the program above yields:

```
 #<NameError: uninitialized constant HelloWorld::Foo>
 #<NameError: uninitialized constant HelloWorld::Foo>
 Foo
```

Or else this program might be easier:

```
class Dog
  def bark
    puts "woa"
  end
end
```

Which code will yield no exception:

```
Dog::bark.new
```

or

```
rex = Dog.new
rex.bark
```

?